# What abilities can be blocked by sivir's/nocturne's spell shield?

Tags: league-of-legends

Mainly, im wondering what ultimates would be blocked, and other spells that have long casts. But if you have a list that would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Spell shields block all **activation** of spells (Starts of channels included).
- They do **not** block DoTs during the effect.
- They do **not** break targeted channeled effects (Fiddle's drain as an example)
- They **do** block spells of any type as long as it's a targeted single-hit spell (Magical, Physical and On-Hit effects) (For Requiem, the shield can be cast to block the damage part post-channel)
- They do block ONE tick out of series of persistent damage abilities. (Panth's HSS, Kennens Maelstrom.)

There are several things I'm still not sure of, such as how Viktor's CC field and Ultimate are affected, or how the shields reacts to on-hit effects.

Comment: I know they do not stop AoE abilities like Viktor/Anivia's ultimates. I would assume Viktor's CC field would still slow/stun both as it is not a targeted skill, but that is still one that would be better of tested.

Comment: Would they stop the beginning of a targetted channel? For example if you use the shield and then fiddle casts his drain on you?

Comment: @Lyrion this is a oncast-block and thus falls under 1), but that is extremely seldom to happen, as you can not really know when fiddle is gonna gast his drain. this works in the same way as karthus' ultimate. you can cancel it, if you cast the spell before the ultimate is cast, but the damage will be applied as soon as the ult channels

Comment: @Vogel612 Depends really, if you see fiddle making a run for you, you can be sure he is either going to cast his fear/silence or drain. But I wonder if you get him to cast his drain and you had your shield up will it cancel the full drain or only 1 tick of the drain. As for Karths ulti, can't you cancel it right before the damage hits?

Comment: @Lyrion look into the answer. he says, that targeted channeled effects(like karth ult) can not be broken, if not interrupted on cast. i have already once cancelled a karth ult with noct shield (was quite funny to live with 50 hp) and i have also been cancelled by a siv spellshield as fiddle. the full drain is cancelled because the effect is not even applied, but the drain goes on cooldown

Comment: @Vogel612 Actually, Karthus ult can be canceled just before the damage ticks...

Comment: @user1337 was new to me, but i have to admit, i have played neither sivir nor nocturn in a while and a karthus as opponent is not so usual anymore

Answer (score -3):

Every attack! Even basic attacks like NASUS's Q, hope this was a good helper!