# Sivir Spellshield Vs. Tether spells

Tags: league-of-legends

When should I cast my spell shield? Should I cast it before (for example) Nocturne casts his fear, or time it so that it's up when the fear procs?

Comment: In case you want any further info on spell shields:
http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/105682/what-abilities-can-be-blocked-by-sivirs-nocturnes-spell-shield/141750#141750

Also, don't forget to accept answers ;L

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use Spell Shield before Nocturne uses Fear, otherwise the fear won't be blocked. The damage will also be negated if you use it before.

[Lolwiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Nocturne) says:

> Spell shields will block the application of the tether but will not block the fear from a tether already present.

Comment: can't believe the wiki mentions something so obscure.

Comment: @Paralytic Tethers make up a fair amount of abilities, so it's not that obscure. Plus, if you try it out a few times you'll quickly pick it up anyway.

Comment: @schism that is true, I was just thinking about nocturne's tether.